# Memory leak in linked list of strings

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, stdstring

I have made a templated doubly linked list. In my destructor I call delete on all of the nodes. I do not have memory leaks with any primitives as a result, but if I create a linked list of std::string, I have leaks. I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
node_pointer next(first);
first = first->_next;
delete next;
```

I call the above while looping through the linked list.

Comment: What do you call in the destructor of your nodes?

Comment: For starter, show us your code !

Comment: How do you know that you have leaks? Some tools are bad at analysing STL containers due to there doing fancy things with memory.

Comment: I'm using the boost auto test framework.

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Oh that thing gives me no end of trouble: I stopped using it a long time ago. I even think it's a known issue with boost and some STLs. Other memory detection tools are much better.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue. I ended up having to make the destructor virtual. As soon as I put the virtual keyword there, memory leaks were gone.